# Deleting several words

Tags: key-bindings

Suppose I've got the following sentence:

```
This |is a sentence for testing purposes.
```

I want this sentence to be

```
This purposes.
```

In fact I want to delete 5 words. Of course, I could do it just as `d5w` but this is so inconvenient and painful. I have to count the words first and then execute the appropriate combination.

I tried it the other way. I pushed `d` and then I tried to push `w` 5 times. But it started deleting lines (and that's sensible, because `dd` deletes a line).

Is there a way to perform word deletion like we did in general editors (we keep pressing `Ctrl` and then press `Del` 5 times) but in Vim. I suppose this quite common operation and there must be a "fast" solution for it.

Comment: `dtp` (delete till the next `p`) would work in this case. If you're not sure, `vtp` `d` so you see what would you delete. More general (, `d/ p` `Enter` to delete till the searched item, or again, to see what you're doing, `v/ p` `Enter` `d` ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meet your friend the dot command!

[`:h .`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#.)

Press <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> (or <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>) to delete a word and repeat the command with <kbd>.</kbd>

From the doc:

> ```
> .          Repeat last change, with count replaced with [count].
>            Also repeat a yank command, when the 'y' flag is
>            included in 'cpoptions'.  Does not repeat a
>            command-line command.
> ```

Note that the dot command works amazingly with the undo workflow of Vim. You can repeat the last change as many time as you want with <kbd>.</kbd> and if you realized you used it too many time simply use <kbd>u</kbd> to undo the change. Want to finally redo the change? Use <kbd>Ctrl+r</kbd>

---

Also as VanLaser noted in his comment there is other ways to delete several words. In addition to his <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> idea note that you can also do that:

- Press <kbd>d</kbd>
- Begin a search <kbd>/</kbd>
- Type the pattern matching the end of the deletion (here `purpose` for example)
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I already recommended it a lot of time on this site, but I think every one who want learn how to use Vim should read [Practical Vim](https://pragprog.com/book/dnvim/practical-vim) that's an amazing reference to learn the basic commands like `.`

Comment: Alternatively: `5dw`, or `d5w` (same thing in this particular case). The catches: you need to start at the beginning of the first word, and your count of 5 needs to be correct.

Comment: It's not worth posting as an answer, but it might supplement yours. You could also start visual mode and hit `w` until it looks like what you want to delete. Or, probably more practical would be hitting `e` a bunch of times.